# Minimizing main form and hide it form taskbar issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I develop winforms program that works as alternative to windows service to do a notification popup,
In main form of windows forms application I do the following properties:
WindowState = Minimized
ShowInTaskbar = false

when set this properties and run application the antivirus detects my program as torjan named:
Trojan VHO:Trojan.MSIL.Convagent.gen

How to solve this problem, and why it occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to solve this problem

Exclude your source directory from realtime scans.

> why it occurs

[Heuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_analysis), i.e. "behavior". An executable that tries to hide itself, might be a virus. It's an overzealous scanner.

Do note that your consumers may experience the same when they download your application.

See also:

- [My C# program is detected as a virus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960407/my-c-sharp-program-is-detected-as-a-virus)
- [Antivirus False positive in my executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339136/antivirus-false-positive-in-my-executable)

So: exclude the directory from scans during development, and report the final application to virus scanner vendors as false positives, so they might include your app's definition in their allowlist.

Comment: there is no any way to mark program as safe on antiviruses ?

Comment: If a developer could mark their application as "definitely not a virus", that would kind of beat the entire purpose of virus scanners, wouldn't it? Again, you can send in your executable to virus scanner vendors to have them analyze it, and if it's definitely not malicious, they may add it to a "known safe" list. You'd have to do this for every version of your application.